# Hot to limit the HLS ts segments counter

Tags: ffmpeg, hls

I've been trying to live stream an IP camera by feeding the rtsp video to FFMPEG. I can see the ts segments are created and old ones deleted, but the names of the ts keep increasing in count. Like right now there are in:

cam22000.ts
cam22001.ts

Is there a way to limit the count only to a range, like 1 through 20 for example?

I wonder if at some point the count will reset after a super high number or if the operating system will crash? The command I'm using is the following:

ffmpeg.exe -i rtsp://IP-Address -acodec copy -vcodec copy -f hls -hls_flags delete_segments+append_list -start_number 1  -hls_time 5 -hls_list_size 6 -hls_delete_threshold 6 C:\hls/camxyz.m3u

Answer (score 0):

That would be bad. The files are designed to be cached. The CDN or player could cache the file and play the wrong segment, and the video could appear to skip backward and forward randomly.